# Selecting From the drop downs in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to enter values 3 values in the drop down using for loop however I am unable to inject the data. I am using a Select class as the drop down is static below is the snap shot and code which I am implementing. Can you please help me where I am doing wrong. Also as I am entering the value as "7 years old" for all the three drop down boxes however if I want to add some other values as well how can I do that as well in the loop?

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

driver.get("https://www.booking.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Where are you going?']"))).send_keys("Jaisalmer")
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@data-label,'Suryagarh ')]"))).click()

for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bui-calendar__control bui-calendar__control--next']"))).click()


#select the checkin date
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@aria-label='22 June 2022']"))).click()
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@aria-label='25 July 2022']"))).click()

#class name = xp__guests__count

wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "xp__guests__count"))).click()

#Increase number of adults 

adultaddition = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-label='Increase number of Adults']")))

for _ in range(7):
    adultaddition.click()

#Increase number of childern

for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(0.7)
    wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-label='Increase number of Children']"))).click()


#adding children ages

agelist = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//select[@name='age']")

for button in agelist:
    time.sleep(0.7)
    dropdown = Select(agelist)
    selectchilderen = dropdown.select_by_visible_text("7 years old")
    button.click()
```

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck? Which line? Which step? Update the question with the manual steps to repro the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake here is in this line:

```py
dropdown = Select(agelist)
```

It should be

```py
dropdown = Select(button)
```

there.
Also, no need to perform `button.click()`.
So, instead of

```py
for button in agelist:
    time.sleep(0.7)
    dropdown = Select(agelist)
    selectchilderen = dropdown.select_by_visible_text("7 years old")
    button.click()
```

It should be

```py
for button in agelist:
    time.sleep(0.7)
    dropdown = Select(button)
    selectchilderen = dropdown.select_by_visible_text("7 years old")
```

As about selecting changing values in the drop list, you can for example add the loop index to the value you are selecting, like the following:

```py
for index, button in enumerate(agelist):
    time.sleep(0.7)
    dropdown = Select(button)
    selectchilderen = dropdown.select_by_visible_text(str(7 + index) + " years old")
```

Comment: Thanks @Prophet also for instance if i want to add three different values like 8 years old and 9 years old so on can i do that in this for loop

Comment: Already added that. I was exactly on that :) This selects 7,8,9 years there